# A question involving non-integer bases and integer exponents

Tags: elementary-set-theory, recreational-mathematics

I'm a high school math student. My last math class was Algebra $2$ Honors, so I'm not super well-versed when it comes to set theory - that being said, since I first thought about this problem, it's been nagging at me.

Let there be two variables, a and b, defined like this:
$a \in \Bbb{R}$, $a \notin \Bbb{Z}$, and $b \in \Bbb{Z}$.
By those constraints, could the statement $a^b \in \Bbb{Z}$?

For the record, I know that $b^a$ can! For example, if $a = 1.5$ and $b = 9$, then $b^a = 9 \times 3 = 27$, and $27 \in \Bbb{Z}$.

EDIT: I saw an answer using $a = \root\of2$ and $b = 2$, which works perfectly! I do wonder, though: Could you extrapolate this any further?
For example, if $a \in \Bbb{Q}$, could there still be a set of values where $a^b \in \Bbb{Z}$? :)

Comment: Posting relates to a classic problem: if $~a,b \in \Bbb{R}, ~a \not\in \Bbb{Q}, ~b \not\in \Bbb{Q}, ~$ can $a^b$ be rational.  Answer: Consider $$M = \sqrt{2}^{(\sqrt{2})} \implies M^{(\sqrt{2})} = 2.$$  Either $M$ is rational or it isn't.  **Edit**: I'm unsure, but I suspect that $M$ has been recently proven to be irrational, not that it matters for the classic problem.

Comment: "recently", in this case, being 1929.

Comment: If $a$ is rational but not an  integer, and $b$ is an integer, then the only way $a^b$ could be an integer is if $b=0$, or if $a$ is the reciprocal of an integer and $b$ is negative. This is easy to show from the Unique Factorization Theorem.

Comment: @user2661923 Your $M$ is the square root of the [Gelfond–Schneider constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_constant)

Comment: @GerryMyerson good point as I cannot edit a  comment I will delete it.  You are saying that reciprocals of integers raised to the power of a negative integer will give an integer

Comment: Yes, @Henry, that's what I did say, in my comment of 2022-08-17 02:33:41Z.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take $a=\sqrt{2}$ and $b=2$, $a^b=2\in Z$